# Get value inserted in RowGuid?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

i have a simple table "MyTable" with single colum "id" which type is uniqueidetifier and rowguid is set to true. I insert new values like this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
DEFAULT VALUES
```

how to get inserted by server guid ?
Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact that you were using a GUID...should have paid more attention to the question. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are on at least SQL Server 2005 use the `OUTPUT` clause.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE 
(
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID()
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
OUTPUT inserted.id
DEFAULT VALUES
```